# different calls when IsPost is activated in cshtml

Tags: c#, html, forms, razor

How can I call different postbacks in cshtml?

```
@{
    Page.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

    if(IsPost)
    {
        // if btn1 is pressed do this

        // if btn2 is pressed do this
    }
}

<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="btn1" />
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="btn2" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Is there a way to tell which one is pressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a "name" attribute for the buttons for them to get registered as part of the submitted form, and the with the value you can determine the submitted button.

```
@{
    if ( IsPost ) {
       switch ( Request.Form[ "btn" ] ) {
          case "btn1":
              <h2>It was btn1</h2>
              break;
        case "btn2":
              <h2>It was btn2</h2>
              break;
      }
   }
}
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="btn1" />

        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="btn2" />
    </form>
</div>
```